# Is it possible to apply force to a light particle?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, visible-light, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

I know, the universal speed limit is the speed of light $c$.  So, is it possible to apply more force to a light particle?  What would happen to it if we could?

Comment: I tried finding a similar question, failed and gave up.  But thank you for the understanding you have provided me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A force is defined as a change in momentum over time. In the Newtonian limit, this means a mass times an acceleration. But when dealing with things like photons, the formal definition is applied.

Photons have no mass, only momentum. Therefore, if a force is applied to them, their momentum can be changed. This can happen in two important ways, a force can change the direction or the magnitude of the momentum. Changing the direction means the light is reflected, scattered, refracted, or curved. Changing the magnitude means that the frequency of the light is changed. Gravity can accomplish this as can a reflection off of a moving object (nothing can hit a photon from behind, so any momentum change from hitting the photon will have to reflect it).

Gravity can and does apply force to photons. When entering a gravity well, the photon falls in. It gains momentum, as most inward falling objects do, which blue-shifts the frequency. When leaving a gravity well, the photon loses momentum, which red-shifts the frequency.

Comment: Hi. I found this to be a very good and interesting answer. Could you say if you may have other phenomena in your mind that might cause change to the frequency of the light? Thank you.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack That depends. Does the original photon have to remain intact? By that, I mean is it simply the frequency changing? Or could a process that consumes one photon and produces another at a different frequency count in this case?

Comment: I think the second could count as well as the first. What I have in mind is if the propagation of light from one mean to another could somehow change it's frequency and, as comment before, if in general we can find other phenomena that might change the frequency of the photon. So, if you can elaborate on this, you would be offering much help to me. Thus, consider, if you can, both of the cases you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack The frequency can be changed by the expansion of space, spontaneous pair-production, scattering, red/blue-shifting events. This might be better suited as a stand-alone question. See if this has been asked before and, if not, ask it as a new question. That would give more room for thorough answers

Comment: "a force can change the direction" - how does that transmit energy? Interestingly, your answer mentions "gravitational blue-shift" which is in stark contrast to Einstein's photon from the sun being changed in direction - only, not in wavelenght. Thus not in energy? In fully "elastic scattering" is there any force that "works". Does the change of direction amount to change of energy of the photon or defracting particle? With radial force and mass it does. Food for thought - massless photon's Direction might be force acting  without reactio (why should a photon attract the earth like a needle).

Comment: "A force is defined as a change in momentum over time." - As you mention blue-shift, a photon that "falls in" might have been deviated by earth (or the moon, Einstein's anecdote, eclipse of the sun), and in default of mass that shouldn't be change of momentum, hence no force applied, which sounds like some paradox. Then, there is "time": is there "no time" involved when a photon is refracted in a mirror without any change in frequency (colour), thus no force and no change of momentum in fully "elastic scattering"?

Comment: @PeterBernhard The energy of a photon is equal to its magnitude of momentum times the speed of light in a vacuum. Changing the energy of a photon, thus, changes its momentum. Changing its direction would also change the momentum, but not the energy. Gravitational deflection is an example of changing direction. Blue-shifting is an example of changing energy. Both change the momentum vector over the time observed.

Comment: Very clear and helpful advice, thanks a lot.  Just one thing:  It's understood that there is "always" time involved, and there is always a Delta? Momentum is said to be a vector, but the direction I have never seen mentioned in formulas over the time observed. Gravitational deflection can be imagined as a curved line; reflection of in a mirror seems instantanous. What time would the delta need for direction change of a photon in mirror...?

Comment: @PeterBernhard I don't know off-hand the limit on the time required, but I do know it is very tiny. On the order of the Planck time. That's for a general change in direction. The thing about mirrors that makes it even easier is that the photon momentum isn't simply reversed. Photons are absorbed by the reflecting medium and reemitted as identical photons with mirrored momentum. That helps to remove discontinuities in the derivative

Comment: I will stop commenting in fear of being removed to chat. Maybe you want to tell, in your answer or in comment, what the formula is "When entering a gravity well," that would be helpful for beginner: please write the formula for the blue-shift. Then, why not write the formula for the "Changing the direction means the light is reflected, scattered...". Thank you for all the advice you gave!